# Forecasting a DCCGARCH model estimated by the ccgarch package

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, garch, volatility-forecasting

How can one predict a dcc-garch model in R using parameters estimated from `dcc.estimation` from the package `ccgarch`?

MWExample:

```
  # Simulating data from the original DCC-GARCH(1,1) process
  nobs <- 1000; cut <- 1000
  a <- c(0.003, 0.005, 0.001)
  A <- diag(c(0.2,0.3,0.15))
  B <- diag(c(0.75, 0.6, 0.8))
  uncR <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0, 0.12, 0.3, 0.12, 1.0),3,3)
  dcc.para <- c(0.01,0.98)
  dcc.data <- dcc.sim(nobs, a, A, B, uncR, dcc.para, model="diagonal")


# Estimating a DCC-GARCH(1,1) model
  dcc.results <- dcc.estimation(inia=a, iniA=A, iniB=B, ini.dcc=dcc.para, 
        dvar=dcc.data$eps, model="diagonal")

# Parameter estimates and their robust standard errors
  dcc.results$out
```

Comment: What do you mean by *predict a model*?

Comment: @RichardHardy Mean predictions and standard error for some $n$ steps ahead.